# Upgrade redmine from 1.0.1 to 3.1.1

Tags: redmine

I want to upgrade from 1.0.1 to 3.1.1
what are the steps? and what is prerequists to install 3.1.1?

what is ruby version and gem is compatible with 3.1.1 ?

thnx in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Redmine 3 runs Rails 4 so it's prerequisites apply. You should at least run Ruby 2.0.

Redmine itself is easily upgraded,
everything else depends on which plugins you are running if any, and if these are still maintained and available in a version compatible with Redmine 3.1.